# In flink when I am using assignTimestampsAndWatermarks() with interface AscendingTimestampExtractor()..i am getting deprecation message

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

What are the alternatives to this code to prevent deprecation.
I have even used assignTimeStamp Interface as well,but i am getting error with that

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> sum = data.map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<Long, String>>()
                {
                    public Tuple2<Long, String> map(String s)
                    {
                        String[] words = s.split(",");
                        return new Tuple2<Long, String>(Long.parseLong(words[0]), words[1]);
                    }
                })
                
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple2<Long, String>>()
                        
                {
                    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple2<Long, String> t)
                    {
                        return t.f0;
                    }
                })
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Tuple2<Long, String>>()
                        {
                    public Tuple2<Long, String> reduce(Tuple2<Long, String> t1, Tuple2<Long, String> t2)
                    {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.f1);
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.f1);
                        int sum = num1 + num2;
                        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        return new Tuple2<Long, String>(t.getTime(), "" + sum);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#introduction-to-watermark-strategies):

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.SerializableTimestampAssigner;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment flink = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStreamSource<String> data = flink.fromElements("hello", "world");
        data.map((MapFunction<String, Tuple2<Long, String>>) s -> {
                    String[] words = s.split(",");
                    return new Tuple2<>(Long.parseLong(words[0]), words[1]);
                }
        ).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<Tuple2<Long, String>>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                .withTimestampAssigner((SerializableTimestampAssigner<Tuple2<Long, String>>) (element, recordTimestamp) -> element.f0))
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .reduce((ReduceFunction<Tuple2<Long, String>>) (t1, t2) -> {
                    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.f1);
                    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.f1);
                    int sum = num1 + num2;
                    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    return new Tuple2<>(t.getTime(), "" + sum);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please cross check the code. It's not executing

Comment: @PrashantSahoo The code was not meant to be executable, it was meant to demonstrate watermark assignment only.